# Horizontal Not Vertical Display?

Tags: php, css

I have info pulled out of a sql database ( I know mysql is deprecated, I'll be switching soon ). Anyway, the info is automatically displayed vertically. Instead, I would like it to be displayed horizontally.

Template.php (Part of it) I have to fix the nbsp, and I do realize I have a few errors.

```
    <?php 
    $channel_check = mysql_query("SELECT content, Date FROM wgo WHERE Posted_By='$user' ORDER by `id` DESC;");
    $numrows_cc = mysql_num_rows($channel_check);
    if ($numrows_cc == 0) {
    echo ''; // They don't have any channels so they need to create one?><h4> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspYou haven't posted anything yet. You can post what's going on in your life, how you're feeling, or anything else that matters to you.</h4>


 <?php
}
else
{
?>
<div id="recentc">
</div>
<?php
echo"<h2 id='lp'> Latest Posts</h2>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($channel_check)) {
  $channel_name = $row['content'];
 ?>
 <div style="margin-top:60px;">
 <hr style="margin-right:340px;width:600px; opacity:0;">

            <?php echo "<div id='rpc'><h6> $channel_name</h6></div>";?>
   </div>
```

Styling:

```
#rpc {
color:#6E6E6E;
font-size:25px;
margin-left:420px;
font-family:Tahoma, Courier New, monospace;

margin-right:100px;
}
```

Okay, so I did everything that was suggested. It's better, but looks really funky now. Here's how the code looks like now.

```
     <?php
}
else
{
?>
<div id="recentc" style="display:inline-block;">
</div>
<?php
echo"<h2 id='lp'> Latest Posts</h2>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($channel_check)) {
  $channel_name = $row['content'];
 ?>


            <?php echo "<div id='rpc'><h6> $channel_name</h6></div>";?>
   </div>
```

and

```
    #rpc {
color:#6E6E6E;
font-size:25px;
margin-left:420px;
font-family:Tahoma, Courier New, monospace;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:100px;

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hautR.png

Comment: if you want the `<h4>` to be on the right, add `float:right;` to the css add : `h4 {float:right;}`

Comment: Have you tried adding "display:inline-block;" to your #rpc?

Comment: BuddhistBeast is right, but rpc should be a class becuase there's multiple and you need to add `display:inline-block` to the hr and all parent dives for each element (Also the width has to be >1200px to see them side-by-side because that's the width of hr

Comment: So, basically I should add display:inline block to all the parent divs, but what should i make greater than 1200 px? Thanks for all your answers so much!

Comment: Nothing, because you set the width of the `<hr>` to 600px it will only appear beside another element if you have a width > 1200px otherwise they'll overflow to the next line

Comment: @Ertyguy, can you help me out a bit? I included a pic in the description, can you click on it? Thanks! :D

Comment: The reason the columns aren't aligning is that the width of the elements change depending on how much text there is. A good way to find out what's going on is to hit F12 and use the magnifying glass to inspect the elements and add css as you see fit. Also ids should only be used on elements that appear once, otherwise use a `class` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a class to the elements and in CSS use `display:inline-block`. You can also `float:left` to your first element too. Then you could use a width % for each element so they're flexible.

Also don't use `&nbsp` for spacing like that. Just use padding or margins in CSS too.